# ${parameter:?word} expansion: `\}` difference between bash and zsh

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

I'm trying to get a literal `}` in the output of the [`${parameter:?word}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#:%7E:text=echo%20%24var%0ADEFAULT-,%24%7Bparameter%3A%3Fword%7D,-If%20parameter%20is) expansion in `zsh`.

In bash, it works as expected -- I can quote the `}` with a `\`:

```
% bash           
$ echo "${unset_var_name?Here is a close brace >>\}<<}" 
bash: unset_var_name: Here is a close brace >>}<<
```

But I can't work out how to do the same in zsh:

```
% zsh                                                                                           
% echo "${unset_var_name?Here is a close brace >>\}<<}" 
zsh: unset_var_name: Here is a close brace >>\}<<
```

Note that the `\` appears literally above.

Comment: It's been reported and fixed already in zsh IIRC. Maybe not released yet.

Comment: Probably https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00036.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't remember that [*I* was the one actually reporting it](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00032.html)!

Comment: Cheers, @StéphaneChazelas!  Glad to see you reported expansion for `word` also.  Is there a way to track the progress of your bug report?

Comment: It was fixed in February by the patch in the first link I gave above, so it is in the development version and will be in the next release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that, and the fact that `$var2` is not expanded for instance in `${var1?$var2}` was an unnecessary and unfortunate deviation from all other shells and from the POSIX specification of `sh` and was [fixed in zsh in February 2023](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00036.html), so will be available in the next release whether that's 5.10 or 6.0.